# Python webdriver Htmlunit // Find_element_by_id make me an error

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, paypal, htmlunit-driver

I would like `Find_element_by_id` on paypal in order to confirm the checkout, but I'm getting an error.
I use a working code with webdriver Chrome and Opera:

```
confirmButton = browser.wait.until(
  EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "confirmButtonTop"))
)
confirmButton.click()
```

I want to use it with `HTMLUnit` and `PhantomJS`, but it doesn't work. I've tried using a different method but nothing:

```
try:
  WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    driver.find_element_by_id('confirmButtonTop'))
  )
  print "Page is driver!"
except TimeoutException:
  print "Loading took too much time!"
```

or:

```
confirmButton = driver.find_element_by_id("confirmButtonTop")
confirmButton.click()
```

same error :

> Unable to locate element with ID: confirmButtonTop

HTML:

```
<div id="button" class="buttons reviewButton">
  <input track-submit="" type="submit" value="Continuer" id="confirmButtonTop" 
         class="btn full confirmButton continueButton" validate-submit="onPay()">
</div>
```

Comment: html code :
<div id="button" class="buttons reviewButton">
<input track-submit="" type="submit" value="Continuer" id="confirmButtonTop" class="btn full confirmButton continueButton" validate-submit="onPay()">
 </div>

Comment: Can you please describe the process, and what you are trying to achieve? Also, using the StackOverflow styling controls in the editor would go a long way..